# virtualenv still looking for system dependencies

Tags: python, virtualenv

the problem is that I get the following, inside of a virtualenv when I check/print the sys path:

```
/Users/myuser/ais/bin
/Users/myuser/ais/lib/python27.zip
/Users/myuser/ais/lib/python2.7
/Users/myuser/ais/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Users/myuser/ais/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Users/myuser/ais/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/myuser/ais/Extras/lib/python
/Users/myuser/ais/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Users/myuser/ais/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Users/myuser/ais/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/myuser/ais/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I already tried

```
which python
which pip
```

within the virtual environment and it looked fine.

I also tried

```
unset $PYTHONPATH
```

without effect.

Any recommendation how I can solve this? I want virtualenv to run completely independent from my global settings and packages.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Best
sc

Comment: How did you create the virtualenv? What version of Python and any other relevant tools are you using?

Comment: Normal way, via virtualenv foo. Python 2.7. Not aware of other tools effecting depencies of python, just Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Okay, but Python 2.7 point what? What version of `virtualenv`? In any case, try recreating the environment with `--no-site-packages`. (Newer versions of `virtualenv` omit system packages by default.)

Comment: Got it. `virtualenv` in V15.1.0 (due to PyPI this should be fine) and Python in version 2.7.10. I also tried `--no-site-packages`, but the `/System/...` depencies are still there.